# Java Swing design

Tags: java, swing

I have a question regarding coding a Swing UI. If I want to make a software with some option e.g. on the first Frame I have three buttons (New, Option, Exit).

Now if a user clicks the new button, I want to change the entire content in the Frame to something else. I know I have to use `addActionListener` to that button. But my question is how to change the contents in the frame. Creating new Frames and then use `setVisible()` isn't an option for me.

And to use `frame.remove()` all the objects seems awkward if it is several things that needs to be removed. Or is it the right way?

Answer (score 5):

Look into the [Card Layout](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). I would also probably use menu items instead of buttons.

Comment: frame.remove() is not ideal.

CardLayout is the correct answer.

Comment: Hey camickr, I'm surprised you're not harassing this person for the SSCCE.... WOW!!

Answer (score 5):

[CardLayout](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) is indeed the better choice in this case; but, when the occasion demands, a [Component](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html) may be removed from a [Container](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html) using either the `remove()` or `removeAll()` method. Afterward, the essential step is to invoke the [`validate()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#validate()) method to lay out the container's subcomponents again. Oscar Reyes' example uses the [Frame](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html)'s [`pack()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack()) method, inherited from [Window](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html), to achieve this effect. In this [example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/buttons), the `resetGame()` method reconstructs the display panel in a similar way.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `frame.remove()`

The difference is that you may remove a whole panel instead of removing "several" things, and you just replace it with a new panel

```
frame.add( mainPanel );
...
// in the action listener 
frame.remove( mainPanel );
frame.add( theNewPage );
```

The point is, you don't have to be afraid of removing awkwardly things in the main frame, for you have to place all those things into a single panel and then just change panels.

**UPDATE**

I've made the code needed to test what I'm talking about.

Here's a running sample:

[alt text http://img190.imageshack.us/img190/5206/capturadepantalla200912p.png](http://img190.imageshack.us/img190/5206/capturadepantalla200912p.png)

later

[alt text http://img301.imageshack.us/img301/1368/capturadepantalla200912n.png](http://img301.imageshack.us/img301/1368/capturadepantalla200912n.png)

Here's the running sample:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ChangePage {
    JComponent mainPage;
    JComponent newPage;
    JFrame     frame;

    public static void main( String [] args ) {
        ChangePage changePageDemo = new ChangePage();
        changePageDemo.show();
    }
    private void show(){
        frame = new JFrame("Demo");
        frame.add( getMainPage() );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }
    private JComponent getMainPage() {
        if( this.mainPage != null ) {
            return this.mainPage;
        }
        this.mainPage = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        mainPage.add( new JLabel("Choose an option") );
        mainPage.add( new JPanel(){{
            add( new JButton("New"){{
                addActionListener( new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ){
                        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable(){
                            public void run(){
                                frame.remove( getMainPage() );
                                frame.add( getNewPage() );
                                //frame.setContentPane( getNewPage() );
                                frame.pack();

                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }});
            add( new JButton("Options"));
            add( new JButton("Exit"));
        }}, BorderLayout.SOUTH );
        return this.mainPage;

    }
    private JComponent getNewPage() {
        if( newPage != null ) {
            return newPage;
        }
        this.newPage = new JPanel();
        this.newPage.add( new JLabel("<html>This is the \"new\" page.<br> Do you like it?<br></html>"));
        this.newPage.add( new JButton("Return"){{
            addActionListener( new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ){
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable(){
                        public void run(){
                            frame.remove( getNewPage() );
                            frame.add( getMainPage() );
                            //frame.setContentPane( getMainPage() );
                            frame.pack();

                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }});
        return this.newPage;
    }

}
```

Alternatively you may use `setContentPane` :)

Comment: @Oscar - You probably received a down vote due to the fact that frame.remove is not the correct way to solve this.  See camickr's answer for the correct way (CardLayout).  Note: I did not down vote you.

Comment: @Jason: Probably. That's fine, I mean I think it would be better if the downvoter explains what's wrong with my answer. Just to understand. Actually your comment make sense.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a [Tabbed Pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html).