# jtabbedpane different sized tabs

Tags: swing, netbeans, jtabbedpane

im making a search function for a database that uses a jtabbedpane with one tab for a quick search, and one for an advanced search. the advanced search has quite a few more fields, so it needs to be larger, but i dont want the whole window to always be at the largest size for aesthetic reasons. i have added a change listener to the pane, and tried resizing the pane based on which tab it is, and the code executes when the tab is clicked, but does nothing. ive tried using tabbedSearchPane.setSize() followed by tabbedSearchPane.validate(), as well as resizing components around it using setSize+validate, and nothing seems to do anything. i really just need to know how to ACTUALLY change the size of a jtabbedpane.

Answer (score 1):

As described in [*Preferred Size in Tabs*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html), and as you observed, `JTabbedPane` tries very hard do to accommodate the largest pane. To switch from the larger to the smaller, you have to replace the larger pane with a temporary one having the same size as the smaller and `invalidate()` the tabbed pane; the converse is required to go the other way. It's a struggle. Alternatively, consider using [`CardLayout`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html), mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947812). As you will want to resize the enclosing container, note how this related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947812/java-swing-design/1947936#1947936) uses [`pack()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack%28%29) accordingly.

Comment: This is the best explanation of the behaviour I've found on SO. When you say `invalidate()` is that called `tabLarge.Invalidate()` when you change? I'm struggling to think how to do this.

Comment: No `invalidate()` just marks the container as needing layout on subsequent `validate()` or `pack()`.

Comment: So I need to remove the contents of other tabs, and replace with an empty temp panel when I switch? How do you get that sort of behaviour...changeListener?

Comment: I'm still struggling with this. Perhaps I should post it up as a new question?

Comment: Yes, but also consider the user: is such behavior is really required?

Comment: I've decided no, There are better ways to do things.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem like this without any problems. (My tabbed pane is inherited in an another panel, if it plays any role)

```
tabbedPane.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                switch (tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex()) {
                case 0:
                    tabbedPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1, 230));
                    break;
                case 1:
                    tabbedPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1, 330));
                    break;
                case 2:
                    tabbedPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1, 430));
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
```

and of course when i create my jtabbedpane:

```
tabbedPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1, 230));
```

I repaint-revalidate both jtabbed/parentpanel both after this, but for other reasons...This seems to work without even calling repain/revalidate in any of the panels.

Preview (Red border = other panel)

[image]